# Using ifelse within mutate and handling NA's

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

thanks for your time.

I have a question about using `ifelse` within the `mutate` function.  `ifelse` is from `base` R, while `mutate` is from the `dplyr` package.

My question is about how `ifelse` handles `NA` values.

I have two character vectors: 
`example_character_vector` contains some words and occasional `NA` values while the other vector, `color_indicator`, contains only the words Green, Yellow, and Red.

I want to mutate my dataframe `example_data_frame` to create a new `override_color_indicator` variable that converts some of the yellows to greens depending on a condition in the `example_character_vector`.

Example data:

```
example_character_vector <- c("Basic", NA, "Full", "None", NA, "None", 
NA)
color_indicator <- c("Green", "Green", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow", 
"Red", "Red")

example_data_frame <- data.frame(example_character_vector,
                                color_indicator)
```

This example_data_frame looks like so:

```
  example_character_vector color_indicator
1                    Basic           Green
2                     <NA>           Green
3                     Full          Yellow
4                     None          Yellow
5                     <NA>          Yellow
6                     None             Red
7                     <NA>             Red
```

I am using nested `ifelse` statements within `mutate` to create a new column called `override_color_indicator`.

If `color_indicator` is yellow and the `example_character_vector` contains the word "Full", I want the `override_color_indicator` to be Green (this is a special case within my data).  Otherwise, I would like the `override_color_indicator` to be exactly the same as the `color_indicator`.

Here is my mutate:

```
example_data_frame <- example_data_frame %>% 
  mutate(override_color_indicator = 
          ifelse(color_indicator == "Green",
                 "Green",
            ifelse(color_indicator == "Yellow" & 
                          str_detect(example_character_vector, "Full"),
                   "Green",
                      ifelse(color_indicator == "Yellow" & 
                        !str_detect(example_character_vector, "Full") |
                             color_indicator == "Yellow" & 
                        is.na(character_vector),
                             "Yellow",
                             "Red"))))
```

(Apologies for the formatting - I tried to format this the best I could for Stack Overflow.)

This above code produces this dataframe:

```
  example_character_vector color_indicator override_color_indicator
1                    Basic           Green                    Green
2                     <NA>           Green                    Green
3                     Full          Yellow                    Green
4                     None          Yellow                   Yellow
5                     <NA>          Yellow                     <NA>
6                     None             Red                      Red
7                     <NA>             Red                      Red
```

My problem here is that in line 5, an NA is introduced in the `override_color_indicator` color.  Instead of an NA, I would like it be "Yellow".

For clarity, this is my desired dataframe:

```
  example_character_vector color_indicator override_color_indicator
1                    Basic           Green                    Green
2                     <NA>           Green                    Green
3                     Full          Yellow                    Green
4                     None          Yellow                   Yellow
5                     <NA>          Yellow                   Yellow
6                     None             Red                      Red
7                     <NA>             Red                      Red
```

I've looked quite a bit for an answer, and couldn't find one anywhere.  I could just create a workaround and go back and manually assign the entries to Yellow, but I don't love that option from a programmatic standpoint.

Also, I'm just kind of curious as to why this behavior happens.  I've ran into this problem a few times now.

---

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `case_when` here, but the reason you are getting `NA` is because of the second `ifelse`. One interesting thing about how `NA` propagates in R is that (from the docs) "the result will be NA if the outcome is ambiguous". So because we knew this would be `FALSE` regardless of the `NA`, we have

```r
NA & FALSE
#> [1] FALSE
```

but since this is ambiguous, the `NA` propagates here.

```r
NA & TRUE
#> [1] NA
```

Row 5 has `TRUE` for `Yellow` but `str_detect` will return `NA`, so `ifelse` returns `NA`. You can get around this by adding `& !is.na(example_character_vector)` in that line:

```r
library(tidyverse)
example_data_frame <- structure(list(example_character_vector = c("Basic", NA, "Full", "None", NA, "None", NA), color_indicator = c("Green", "Green", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Red", "Red")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
example_data_frame %>%
  mutate(
    override_color_indicator =
      ifelse(
        color_indicator == "Green",
        "Green",
        ifelse(
          color_indicator == "Yellow" &
            str_detect(example_character_vector, "Full") & !is.na(example_character_vector),
          "Green",
          ifelse(
            color_indicator == "Yellow" &
               (!str_detect(example_character_vector, "Full") | is.na(example_character_vector)),
            "Yellow",
            "Red"
          )
        )
      )
  )
#>   example_character_vector color_indicator override_color_indicator
#> 1                    Basic           Green                    Green
#> 2                     <NA>           Green                    Green
#> 3                     Full          Yellow                    Green
#> 4                     None          Yellow                   Yellow
#> 5                     <NA>          Yellow                   Yellow
#> 6                     None             Red                      Red
#> 7                     <NA>             Red                      Red
```

But definitely use `case_when`!

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead. `case_when` is a more flexible vectorised `if` and allows you to use `TRUE` to say "else, use the value in `color_indicator`.

```r
example_data_frame <- structure(list(example_character_vector = c("Basic", NA, "Full", "None", NA, "None", NA), color_indicator = c("Green", "Green", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Red", "Red")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

library(dplyr)
example_data_frame %>%
  mutate(x = case_when(color_indicator == "Yellow" &
                        example_character_vector == "Full" ~ "Green",
                       TRUE ~ color_indicator))
#>   example_character_vector color_indicator                        x 
#> 1                    Basic           Green                    Green
#> 2                     <NA>           Green                    Green
#> 3                     Full          Yellow                    Green
#> 4                     None          Yellow                   Yellow
#> 5                     <NA>          Yellow                   Yellow
#> 6                     None             Red                      Red
#> 7                     <NA>             Red                      Red
```

Comment: @CalumYou I appreciate the contribution, but I would in general recommend a somewhat lighter touch when editing code in other people's answers.

Comment: will bear that in mind. sorry for overwriting: didn't want to duplicate and i'd already written out the same thing.